# Why CP violation explains matter-antimatter asimmetry?

Tags: standard-model, antimatter, cp-violation

I'm studying Kaon oscillations and the Cronin & Fitch experiment on CP violation. I think I understand why CP is violated in the process but I don't understand why it means that matter and antimatter are treated differently in nature.

The process I'm studying involves Kaon states with even CP eigenvalue decaying in neutral Pions with oposite CP. I don´t see how this would explain matter-antimatter asimmetry...